# Short cut key for Navigation from one file to another file in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In my project i have multiple jsp files. I want to knowsome short cut keys in eclipse IDE. Especially for file navigation. If anyone know tell me the short cut key for file navigation in eclipse neon3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last modified file: Alt+(left and right arrow),
move editer tab: ctrl+shift+f6

Comment: Thanks dear frnd Manihtraa.